# Unit test with Coroutines and Retrofit

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

I created an App using coroutines and retrofit and it works fine. The problem comes when I try to create UT for the Presenter. Here how I made the presenter:

```
class MainPresenter : ViewModel() {

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    private val heroesRepository: HeroesRepository = heroesRepositoryModel.instance()
    private lateinit var listener: ActivityStatesListener

    fun setActivityListener(listener: ActivityStatesListener) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    fun getHeroesFromRepository(page: Int) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            try {
                val response = heroesRepository.getHeroes(page)
                listener.onHeroesReady(response.data.results)
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                listener.onError(e.message())
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                listener.onError(e.message)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        compositeDisposable.dispose()
    }
}
```

I started to make the UT for it and I made a small test but is giving me the following error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize`

```
class HeroesDataSourceTest {

    val heroesRepository: HeroesRepository = mock(HeroesRepository::class.java)
    @Mock
    lateinit var activityListener: ActivityStatesListener

    val hero = Heroes.Hero(1, "superman", "holasuperman", 1, null, null)
    val results = Arrays.asList(hero)
    val data = Heroes.Data(results)
    val dataResult = Heroes.DataResult(data)

    private val mainPresenter = MainPresenter()

    @Before
    fun initTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun testLoadInitialSuccess() = runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main) {
        `when`(heroesRepository.getHeroes(0)).thenReturn(dataResult)
        mainPresenter.getHeroesFromRepository(0)
        verify(activityListener).onHeroesReady(dataResult.data.results)
    }
}
```

Is clear that Dispatcher.Main is giving problems but I have no clue how to solve it.

**EDIT**

The repository used is the following:

```
class HeroesRepository {

    val privateKey = "5009bb73066f50f127907511e70f691cd3f2bb2c"
    val publicKey = "51ef4d355f513641b490a80d32503852"
    val apiDataSource = DataModule.create()
    val pageSize = 20

    suspend fun getHeroes(page: Int): Heroes.DataResult {
        val now = Date().time.toString()
        val hash = generateHash(now + privateKey + publicKey)
        val offset: Int = page * pageSize
        return apiDataSource.getHeroes(now, publicKey, hash, offset, pageSize).await()
    }

    fun generateHash(variable: String): String {
        val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
        val digested = md.digest(variable.toByteArray())
        return digested.joinToString("") {
            String.format("%02x", it)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `heroesRepository.getHeroes(page)` marked as **suspend**, so it will suspend the coroutine and not block the **Main thread**.
Try to follow the next approach:

```
// add `CoroutineContext` to the constructor to be replaceable from the tests
class MainPresenter(private val uiContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main) 
    : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {

    private var job: Job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = uiContext + job

    fun getHeroesFromRepository(page: Int) {
        // use local scope to launch a coroutine
        launch {
            try {
                val response = heroesRepository.getHeroes(page)
                listener.onHeroesReady(response.data.results)
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                listener.onError(e.message())
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                listener.onError(e.message)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        job.cancel()
    }

    // ...
}
```

In the test class replace `uiContext` with another `CoroutineContext`:

```
class HeroesDataSourceTest {
    // ... initializations

    @Test
    fun testLoadInitialSuccess() = runBlocking {
        `when`(heroesRepository.getHeroes(0)).thenReturn(dataResult)
        mainPresenter = MainPresenter(Dispatchers.Unconfined).apply {
            getHeroesFromRepository(0)
        }

        // ... your tests here
    }
}
```

Comment: this fix the problem that I had but now the problem is that the test goes on without waiting to getHeroesFromRepository function to execute so I cannot test that it make what it should make.

Comment: is `getHeroes(page)` function  marked as `suspend`?

Comment: yes it is. I will edit with the repository so you can check it

Comment: All should work. You are mocking `heroesRepository.getHeroes(0)` call, so your `getHeroesFromRepository` function will return quickly enough. Please check again.

Comment: I checked it several times and debug it. When I call `getHeroesFromRepository´ it enters and after the line `val response = heroesRepository.getHeroes(page)` then it goes directly to `verify(activityListener).onHeroesReady(dataResult.data.results)`. I also put break point in both catch but it doesn't continue.

Comment: If you put logs, for example `System.out.println("your log here")` in `getHeroesFromRepository` function, do you see that logs? Is test fails or not? It goes to `verify(activityListener).onHeroesReady(dataResult.data.results)` bcz `listener.onHeroesReady(response.data.results)` has been called, and it should be verified in the test.

Comment: I add logs and it only show me the first one that is before `val response = heroesRepository.getHeroes(page)` I have another log after this line and it is not writing. And the test is failing becuase it says that the verify is true and it says: `Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock`

Comment: Don't see the issue, this is working on my side. Maybe there are some problems with initializations in test class, or the exception is thrown in `getHeroesFromRepository` function, so that `listener.onError` is invoked.

Comment: I also added brake point in the exceptions but it just never arrive there. I really don't know whats it is going on here. Is quite weird that just don't do anything after the first line.

Comment: runBlocking(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
            `when`(mockGbCommunicator?.getAppDetail("url")).thenReturn(response)

            repository?.getAppDetail("url", mockListener!!)
        }

Comment: @here it gives me main missing exception when i ran this code,can any body help

Comment: @Srishti Roy  To use Dispatchers.Main in Android add `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1' ` to the build.gradle file of your module.

Comment: that was already there ,my main class is running fine,test class is causing issue,,main class is something like this

Comment: try {
            loadAppDetail = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val response = gbCommunicator.postFavourites(url)
                withContext(uiScope) {

                    Log.e("TAG", "" + response);
                    if (!response.isError()) {
                        responseListener.onSuccess(result)


                    }

Comment: You can create a new question and describe your problem in details.